# CSS hack for Opera Mini only

Tags: css, opera-mini

Opera Mini doesn't support `line-height` and `font-size` correctly and I have 2 blocks of text (`10px/1 Arial`) — one at the top and one at the bottom of the page, both should be always visible (no scrolling or moving them allowed) but as they take much more space in Opera Mini I've got to downsize and remove some other blocks so there wouldn't be any scrolling (it's critical on mobile devices with small screens like `320x480px`).

I know about JS solution that work perfectly, but I'm not allowed to use any scripts on that page. I can't use any not-standard font either. I'm only allowed to used the internal style sheet.

I couldn't find anything better than `:-o-prefocus` and I use it along with `@media`'s so it would affect only mobile devices with small screens where the text takes much space, but this way it still  affects all Operas on those devices so other blocks are unnecessary small or being removed there.

So basically, the question is — is there any pure CSS solution targeting Opera Mini only?

**Update:**

Eventually, the best non-js solution for the original problem I ended up with was:

```
:-o-prefocus, .block1, .block2 {font-size: 14px;}
@-o-viewport {zoom: 0.75;}
```

Comment: Can you please tell js solution?

Comment: It's https://github.com/sureshdsk/browser-specific-css
Using that script you can write browser-specific css rules, particularly for Opera Mini they should start with .operamini, like say
body {background: #000}
.operamini body {background: #f00}

Comment: You should post your own solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: In case someone is willing to use a JS-based hack for Opera Mini, there are two of them known so far: `Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === '[object OperaMini]'` and `(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera Mini') > -1)`. 

Sources:  
- http://browserhacks.com/#hack-172f62993dedb4837377cf1c6ac9dea9  
- http://browserhacks.com/#hack-70b623e6ee3d3af7c3ca68b71c5fb29f

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, the best non-js solution was:

```
:-o-prefocus, .block1, .block2 {font-size: 14px;}
@-o-viewport {zoom: 0.75;}
```

Comment: As this was confirmed as the answer that works, could someone please accept this? :)